# Avoiding multiple writes to file in Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

After parsing the file row by row I will get the below values like this

```
DAY        | HOUR | Quarter | TYPE | STATUS CODE // this is for telling what below fields indicate
2021-02-29 ,  21   ,2        ,99     200         //only these values get stored in the variable
2021-02-29 ,  21   ,3        ,98     200
2021-02-29 ,  21   ,3        ,99     400
2021-02-29 ,  21   ,3        ,98     200
```

What I am doing is I am parsing the file row by row I am computing this values and inserting into file but that would be very costly.
Below is the code which I implemented:

```
`cat $FILE | grep -v Orig |awk '
BEGIN{ FS="|"; OFS="," }
{
        rg=99;
        dRg=98;
        split($5,RegReqArr,":");
        split($1,dateTime,",");
        split(dateTime[1],date," ")
        split(date[2],time,":")
//for identifying quarter
        if (time[2]<15) { time[2]=1;} else if(time[2]>=15 && time[2]<30) {time[2]=2;} else if(time[2]>=30 && time[2]<45) {time[2]=3;} else { time[2]=4;}
        split($4,successStat,":");
        if (successStat[2]==200) {
                s=1;
        }else {
                s=0;
        }

        if (RegReqArr[2] == 10) { 
                split($11,reqType,":");
                if (reqType[2]>0) {
                        print date[1],time[1],time[2],reg,successStat[2] // here printing it to the file
                } else {
                        print date[1],time[1],time[2],dReg,successStat[2]
                }
        }
        }
}' > output_FILE`
```

What I want to do is instead of writing each row to file I want to store in some place and do one single write to file, Please suggest me some way to alter the existing structure

Comment: my input file contains more than 1000+ entries I am parsing row one by one and writing to file, I am new to shell script I am thinking print does file write for every row , so number of rows in the input file those much write will be there to the file, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: This seems an unnecessary worry.  Before you try to "optimize" things better to measure it first.  1000+ is not a large number.

Comment: it will increase like alot of entries and number of input files also increases that it will lead to problem when the file rotation is set as I cant even finish computing and writing as new set of files gets added and previous files will be moved

Comment: did you `time` it?

Comment: `output_FILE` will be opened **once**, all of the `awk` program output will be written to this open file, and when the `awk` program completes `output_FILE` will be closed; can't really get much more efficient than that (at least in terms of minimizing the overhead for opening/closing a file); if there's a question about the efficiency of the `awk` program itself ... *shrug* ... that's another question entirely and will come down to a detailed analysis of what you're trying to do with `awk`, which in turn will require sample inputs to work with

Comment: is there any way where I can store [2021-02-29 ,  21   ,2        ,99     200] with 0 index and next row in further index. No haven't time it but it can be the case as I cant write each row everytime, any datastructure which can I use in this case here

Comment: @markp-fuso, Got it, Is there any way where I can avoid multiple writes to file and write once all at a time

Comment: When writing to a file, stdout is usually buffered for up to 4K.  Don't do unnecessary optimization without understanding what is happening.  However, you can remove `cat` and `grep` from the script.

Comment: @mark I don't understand the question; your code is only writing to the file once; if you're asking how to have `awk` store everything in memory (eg, via arrays) and then dump the entire array to file at the `END` ... sure, that's doable but would not provide any benefit, in fact, you'd use up more memory and the final dump of the array would have to use a loop that issues separate `print` commands, ie, performing a separate write for each line of output

Comment: @mark Are you thinking that, for example, when `awk` writes out row #500, it also has to re-write rows #1-499? If that's your concern, don't worry about it, because that's not how it works. When it writes #500, it simply adds it after #499, which is already there.